# Loop over li in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am a self taught CS student and I am working on a job listing website. I am not working on the backend page on the site where the user can add or remove any job from the website. Every jobs has different properties and I created 3 mySQL tables to store them. One of the table is `keywords` and has 2 columns `job_id` which is a foreign key from the `job_table` and `keyword`. So a job can have multiple keywords.

[how the backend looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ab00t.png)

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhFVF.png)

So everytime I am adding a new keyword, a new `li` is generated. Right now the array is located at the `input` level `name="keywords[]"` but the size is always equal to zero. However, when I am checking the number of li items directly on the Google Chrome console, it is correct. I am struggling with this problems for days, If someone can help me to fix it it should be nice.

**add-jobs.php**

```
<form id="new-listing" action="add-database.php" method="POST">
    </p>
        <div class="add">
            <label for="keywords">Keywords : </label>     
            <input type="text" class="keywords" name="keywords[]" value=""/>   
            <button class="add-keyword">Add</button>               
        </div>
            <ul class="list-keywords">
                //Here goes new where the user click on the button .add-keyword <li></li>
            </ul>
    <p>
</form>
```

**add-database.php**

```
<?php
    require("../config/db.php");
    require("add-jobs.php");

    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","benoit"); 
    $keywords = $_POST["keywords"];

    mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO keywords (`keywords`)
    VALUES ('$keywords')") 
    or die(mysqli_error($link));      
    ?>
```

**add-jobs.js**

```
const keywords = document.querySelector(".keywords");
const addKeyword = document.querySelector(".add-keyword");
const listKeywords = document.querySelector(".list-keywords");    

const generateTemplate = (word, location) => {
 const html = `
    <li class="individualKeyword"><span>${word}</span>
    <i class="far fa-times-circle delete"></i>
    </li>` ;

 location.innerHTML += html;
};

addKeyword.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    const word = keywords.value.trim();
    console.log(word);
    keywords.value = "";
    generateTemplate(word, listKeywords);
});


listKeywords.addEventListener("click", e =>{
    if(e.target.classList.contains("delete")){
        e.target.parentElement.remove();
   };

}); });
```

I also know the code is not secured yet but I wanna learn the basics first and then protect it against SQL injections.

Comment: Note: your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, used prepared statements!

Comment: Yes I know but I want to be able to insert into the DB first

Comment: Would you be able to help me?

Comment: it seems your keywords are not saved in the db

Comment: no, it does not work, it is not stored in the array so it does not reach the db

Comment: `value=""` remove it and try again

Comment: Thanks dean, I just tried it and now I am getting "Array" instead of NULL. I added 3 keywords and only a new row appeared but the value for the "keywords" column is "Array"

Comment: Do you know how can I get the values and how can I get the exact numbers of li?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if you are only submitting one keyword at a time in your form, you don't need to make the name of the input an arrayed name, so use `name="keyword"` instead of `name="keyword[]"` since that will generate an array.

```
<form id="new-listing" action="add-database.php" method="POST">
    <div class="add">
        <label for="keywords">Keywords : </label>
        <input type="text" class="keywords" name="keywords" value=""/>
        <button class="add-keyword">Add</button>               
    </div>
    <ul class="list-keywords">
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

For the backend, I would recommend either using the object version of `mysqli` or switching to `PDO`. Either are more intuitive than the functional version of `mysqli`. In my opinion PDO is better but since you are using mysqli, I will show that instead:

```
<?php
require("add-jobs.php");
$con = new mysqli("localhost","root","","benoit");
// It's wise to check that this is being sent
if(!empty($_POST["keywords"])) {
    // Trim the keywords to make sure all the front and back spaces are out
    // Remove any possible HTML as well
    $keywords = strip_tags(trim($_POST["keywords"]));
    if(empty($keywords))
        throw new \Exception("Keyword can not be empty.");
    // Prepare the sql
    $query = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO keywords (`keywords`) VALUES (?)");
    // Bind the keyword parameter
    $query->bind_param('s', $keywords);
    // Execute the query
    $query->execute();
    // Release
    $query->close();
}
```

For multiple keywords, keep `keywords[]`:

```
<form id="new-listing" action="add-database.php" method="POST">
    <div class="add">
        <label for="keywords">Keywords : </label>
        <input type="text" class="keywords" name="keywords[]" value="" />
        <input type="text" class="keywords" name="keywords[]" value="" />
        <input type="text" class="keywords" name="keywords[]" value="" />
        <button class="add-keyword">Add</button>               
    </div>
    <ul class="list-keywords">
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Backend would be:

```
<?php
require("add-jobs.php");
$con = new mysqli("localhost","root","","benoit");
// It's wise to check that this is being sent
if(!empty($_POST["keywords"])) {
    // Loop through the array and remove spaces and html
    $keywords = array_filter(array_map(function($v){
        return strip_tags(trim($v));
    }, $_POST['keywords']));
    if(empty($keywords))
        throw new \Exception("Keyword can not be empty.");
    // Prepare the sql
    $query = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO keywords (`keywords`) VALUES (".implode('), (', array_fill(0, count($keywords), '?')).")");
    // Bind the keyword parameter
    $query->bind_param(implode('', array_fill(0, count($keywords), 's')), ...$keywords);
    // Execute the query
    $query->execute();
    // Release
    $query->close();
}
```